# How to create a function that checks if a variable is binary in R?

Tags: r, list, function, variables, binary

I've been assigned a homework assignment that follows

```
Write a function called numeric_summary which takes two inputs:\
`x`: A numeric vector\
`group`: A factor vector of the same length as x

and produces a list as output which contains the following elements:\
`missing`: The number of missing values in x\
`means`: The means of x for each level of groups.\
`sds`: The standard deviations of x for each level of groups\
`p.value`: The p-value for a test of the hypothesis that the means across the levels of groups are the same (versus the two-sided alternative)\
`is.binary`: Set to FALSE for for this function
```

Here is my code so far

```
numeric_summary <- function(x,group) {
  list(missing = sum(is.na(x)),
       means = tapply(x, group,mean,na.rm = TRUE),
       sds = tapply(x, group, sd,na.rm = TRUE),
       p.value = (summary(aov(x ~ group, na.action = na.omit))[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][1]),
       is.binary = apply(titanic4,2,function(x) { all(x %in% 0:1)}))
    }
numeric_summary(titanic4$age,titanic4$pclass)
```

And the output is

```
$missing
[1] 263

$means
     1st      2nd      3rd 
39.15992 29.50670 24.81637 

$sds
     1st      2nd      3rd 
14.54806 13.63863 11.95820 

$p.value
[1] 1.797203e-43

$is.binary
   pclass  survived      name       sex       age     sibsp     parch 
    FALSE      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE 
   ticket      fare     cabin  embarked      boat      body home.dest 
    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE 
   female 
     TRUE
```

What I'm trying to do is to make the is.binary read `FALSE` for x since it is a factor variable and not binary. The current is.binary reads off every column in the data frame, but I just want it so it reads for the one selected.

Comment: It looks like you are applying `all(x %in% 0:1)` to every column of `titanic4` when you really only need to do it once.

Comment: so would I have to still use all or use something else in that case?

Comment: You should use `all` because all the values in `x` should be either 0 or 1.